# Issue when using multiple UIWindows that don't all support landscape mode

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, ios8.1

I have a very simple test iOS8 application that uses two UIWindows. The first window is only allowed to be displayed in portrait mode. When shown, the second window allows AllButUpsideDown.

The button in the first window can be used to show the second window...
[image]

The second window supports landscape mode as shown below...

[image]

If the second window is dismissed (removed) while in landscape, the first window now looks
like below..

[image]

Why is the status bar in left in the landscape position? Also, I noticed the [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds are landscape size?

(Setting the status bar orientation does nothing)

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and thought I'd share..

To force the orientation to change you have to 'present' a view controller that has its preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation method set to the orientation you want. So, in the above case the main window's root view controller can present/dismiss a blank view controller with its preferred orientation set to portrait.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the right part of the "window 2", what happen ? If you look at the point clicked, do you have the right coordinates ?